# colores de filas en datagridview

Tags: datagridview

Al momento de ejecutar un aplicación de escritorio con un formulario llamado FrmActividad tengo una condicion en el evento Load de un DataGridView que ahí tengo, la idea es colorear las filas cuyo estado sea "Abierta" y las colorea bien.

Si lo ejecuto con un formulario: FrmMenu, a partir de este llamo a FrmActividad pero no colorea las filas.

Comment: Podrías pasar los códigos del formActividad y formMenu, si no es imposible saber...

Comment: En las propiedades del proyecto cuando inicio la aplicacion con FrmActividad muestra el resaltado del color que quiero a las filas que cumplen la condicion, todo bien normal.

Pero cuando en las propiedades del proyecto inciio la aplicacon con FrmMenu y doy click sobre la opcion de Actividades, me carga FrmActividades pero no resalta las filas.

Comment: Pero no son el mismo formulario ni datagridview entonces no?

Comment: No. El menú llama al de actividad, pero al cargar el form de Actividad no muestra las filas resaltadas con color, todo esto es cuando el formulario de inicio es del Menú. 

Si coloco el form de Actividad al iniciar la aplicación si me muestra el resaltado en las filas.

Comment: Sin verlo es imposible